# How to find all simple path from a node?

Tags: c, graph, tree

I have a graph like this, and now I want to print out all the path from 0

```
             0
             |
             1 
           /   \
          2 --- 3
          |    / \
          5---6---4
```

expected output

```
All the path from 0 are:
0123465
0123645
0125634
0125643
0132564
0134652
01364
013652
```

I have tried to draw a tree to understand this question.

[image]

And I have tried to program it:

```c
int main(){ 
        ...

        //print  all node
        // choose the start node as 0
        int startV = 0;
        // init the path
        int path = startV;
        // init the visited array; 
        int visited[7] = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1};

        Recur(g, n, 0, path, visited);
}

void Recur(Graph g, int numV, Vertex startV, int path, int *visited) {
    // DFS recursive algorithm

    // mark this node as visited
    visited[startV] = 1;

    // travel all the nodes under startV, 
    for (int i = 0; i < numV; i++) {
        // if there is an edge between node startV and node i && node i haven't visited 
        if (isEdge(newEdge(startV, i), g) && visited[i] == -1) {
            // save and print the path
            path = path * 10 + i;
            printf("path:%d\n", path);
            // recursive: repeat this, i as the startV
            Recur(g, numV, i, path, visited);
        }
    }


}
```

However, my code can only output this.

```
path:1
path:12
path:123
path:1234
path:12346
path:123465
```

I think maybe there are some problems with my visited list and the backtrack method. Could someone please give me some advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't "unvisited" any node.

So when you backtrack you can't follow another route through a node. I suggest you add

```
visited[startV] = -1;
```

at the end of the `Recur` function.

```
void Recur(Graph g, int numV, Vertex startV, int path, int *visited) {

    // mark this node as visited
    visited[startV] = 1;

    //...

    // mark this node as not visited
    visited[startV] = -1;
}
```